# Javascript events on elements at same level

Tags: javascript, svg, event-handling, dom-events

I have two SVG elements in a group. Both belong to separate scope in object model.
Now, I want to capture mouse events on both the elements parallely.

Problem is I am getting event only to the top most element not to the below one.
As both the elements are at same level, I am unable to use capture and bubble.

In the simpler way below is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zLx15u8c/10/

```
var parent = document.getElementById( 'myGrp' );
var telement = document.getElementById( 'telement' );

  var polyConfig = {
      'points': '0,0 500,500',
      'id': 'pLine',
      'fill': 'red',
      'stroke': 'black',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      'appendTo': parent
  };

  var pLine = CreateSvgElement( 'polyline', polyConfig );
  var prect = CreateSvgElement( 'rect',
                                    {
                                        'x': 0,
                                        'y': 0,
                                        'width': 200,
                                        'height': 200,
                                        'stroke': 'black',
                                        'fill-opacity': 0,
                                        'appendTo': parent
                                    } );
prect.addEventListener( 'mousemove', OnRectMouseMove,false );
prect.addEventListener( 'mousedown', OnRectMouseDown, false );

pLine.addEventListener( 'mousemove', OnMouseMove );
pLine.addEventListener( 'mousedown', OnMouseDown );
```

In the example, I want to capture event on line inside the rect.

Answer (score 1):

By creating the polygon first, then creating the polyline, I get the expected output:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrs6ngm5/

```
var prect = CreateSvgElement('rect', {
    'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'width': 200,
        'height': 200,
        'stroke': 'black',
        'fill-opacity': 0,
        'appendTo': parent
});
var polyConfig = {
    'points': '0,0 500,500',
        'id': 'pLine',
        'fill': 'red',
        'stroke': 'red',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        'appendTo': parent
};

var pLine = CreateSvgElement('polyline', polyConfig);
```

Comment: Ok there are further complications here. When mouse right click happens, I want to capture on line and if mouse left click happens I need to capture on rect :(

Comment: I'm pretty certain that svg does not support that kind of interaction.

Comment: Ya even I am guessing that..  But no option with me, need to find a workaround.

Comment: Just managing with changing the layers based of functionality requirement.